# Spring Path first optional Param

Tags: spring-mvc, path

I'm working on **Spring MVC**, I have this method in the controller:

```java
@Path("{p:/?}{ente:(([a-zA-Z]{3})?)}/getEnabledServices")
public RicercheAttive getEnabledServices(@PathParam("ente") String ente) {
    ...
}
```

It accepts */RED/getEnabledServices* **BUT NOT** */getEnabledServices*

I want the first parameter **optional**, but it works only if the parameter *ente* is after *getEnabledServices* as:

```java
@Path("/getEnabledServices/{p:/?}{ente:(([a-zA-Z]{3})?)}")
```

It accepts */getEnabledServices/RED* **AND** */getEnabledServices*

Any suggestion(for first situation)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can properly register endpoint like this, to match none at the beginning. The easiest way to do this, is to make separately methods in controller (like methods overwrite). One to match `/RED/getEnabledServices` and the other to match `/getEnabledServices` .

```
@Path("{ente:([a-zA-Z]{3})}/getEnabledServices")
public RicercheAttive getEnabledServicesWithParam(@PathParam("ente") String ente) {
   ...
}


@Path("/getEnabledServices")
public RicercheAttive getEnabledServicesWithoutParam() {
   ...
}
```

My journey with spring has started since Spring 3.0 release where you have `@RequestMapping` and `@PathVariable`. I wanted to write this as a comment, but I have not enough reputation...